# Applet doesnt reload its source code when page refreshes

Tags: java, browser, applet, refresh

I test a java applet and when I change the code, save it (I use netbeans 7.0.1 and have the "auto-compile on save" option checked on) and refresh the page, the applet doesn't read its new code, but still loads the old code from cache (or from whereever).
I have tried Shift+F5 and Ctrl+F5 with no results. Any better idea then close and open whole browser? (problem stays in chrome and firefox)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>Applet 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <applet code="test/EasyApplet.class" width=400 height=300>
    </applet>
    <br>
    <applet code="test/MyApplet.class" width=400 height=300>
    </applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

Applet:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class EasyApplet extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        add(new Label("and this is even more strange text 13"));
    }

}
```

No cache cleaning helps, but the new applet reloads after refreshing about a minute later.

Comment: What does your html look like? What happens if you manually clear your browser's cache?

Answer (score 0):

Applets should be tested in tools like applet viewer or [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/), which do not cache classes.  If testing in a browser, ensure the Java Console is open (there is an option in the Java Control Panel) & type Ctrl-X (I think that is 'clear class cache') before refreshing the page.

Comment: My applet (i mean the real one) works fine in default Netbeans applet wiever, but added to web page, it doent´s want to load images because of security rights and throws an error (i found out just now)

Comment: Hey, just want to ask, how do i open the java console elsehow then clicking on failed-opened applet?

Answer (score 0):

LOL, now i see all the problem was that my old slow computer takes over 30 seconds to compile the source code :D sorry for bothering.